# Lost uk passport. Due to fly from Jersey to London and London to India tomorrow? How can I get a replacement passport?

Tags: passports, london, officials, lost-documents

I have looked at all info on gov website but although you can make an appointment for an express passport the option is not there if passport is lost. Also where should I go in London. Address please?

Comment: @JSLavertu It's not a good dupe. It's not possible to get a 1-day appointment if you lost your passport

Comment: I don't believe there's any way you can get a replacement passport in time. See linked question in previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference there are several passport offices around the UK where it is possible to get a passport the same day. Some are by appointment only.

For London the [Passport Office](https://www.gov.uk/find-regional-passport-office) is next to Victoria bus and rail station in Pimlico.

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=51.493559,-0.144118&z=16&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=GB&mapclient=embed&cid=12251453642629005833)

Comment: But not for a lost passport

Comment: @Berwyn You can still go to a passport office for a lost, stolen or damaged passport, but they only offer the 1 week fast track service now.